# Multiple for loops inside each other

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've bumped into a problem which really bothers me. I've tried to Google the problem but without luck. I got the following code where I want to apply specific nodes to the DOM, getting the information from an array. The while loop works perfectly fine, but it's when it comes to the "for" loop stuff gets funky. I want to filter the different bits using the "collection_id" from the "bitValues" array up against the "collectionValues" id's. The information which should be applied looks like following:

```
    var bitValues = [{
                    'id': 1,
                    'collection_id': 1,
                    'description': "Amazing description",
                    'radio': "ANR",
                    'date': "01-01-2018",
                    'time': "11:45:00",
                    'seconds': 10,
                    'delta': '8.5',
                    'gain_loss': '2',
                    'total_listeners': '13.343',
                    'delta_listeners': '22.340',
                }, {
                    'id': 2,
                    'collection_id': 2,
                    'description': "DR P3 music is amazing",
                    'radio': "DR P3",
                    'date': "05-01-2018",
                    'time': "13:45:00",
                    'seconds': 16,
                    'delta': '12',
                    'gain_loss': '82',
                    'total_listeners': '15.343',
                    'delta_listeners': '102.340',
                },
                {
                    'id': 3,
                    'collection_id': 2,
                    'description': "Let's go!",
                    'radio': "Nova FM",
                    'date': "25-01-2018",
                    'time': "23:45:00",
                    'seconds': 126,
                    'delta': '53',
                    'gain_loss': '17',
                    'total_listeners': '28.343',
                    'delta_listeners': '22.340',
                }
            ];

let collectionValues = [{
                'id': 1,
                'demographic': "All females",
                'delta': "19.5",
                'gain_loss': "62.126",
                'total_listeners': '43.343',
                'delta_listeners': '22.340',
                bits: bitValues
            }, {
                'id': 2,
                'demographic': "All 12-24",
                'delta': "10.5",
                'gain_loss': "52.126",
                'total_listeners': '153.343',
                'delta_listeners': '132.340',
                bits: bitValues
            }];
```

The jQuery to apply the data looks like this:

```
    while (i < collectionAmount) {
        (Code that works)...

        for (let n = 0; n < bitAmount; n++) {

           collection_id = collectionValues[i].id;
           bit_reference_id = bitValues[n].collection_id;

           if(collection_id == bit_reference_id) {
       $('.freestyle-deltas_details_bits').append(`
<tr>
                                                            <td><span 
    class="font-weight-bold">Bit
                                                                        ${bitValues[n].id}: </span>(
                                                                        ${bitValues[n].time}, ${bitValues[n].seconds} sec)</td>
                                                                    <td><span class="colorChangeByValueDelta">${bitValues[n].delta}%</span></td>
                                                                    <td><span class="colorChangeByValueGainLoss">${bitValues[n].gain_loss}%</span></td>
                                                                    <td>${bitValues[n].total_listeners}</td>
                                                                    <td>${bitValues[n].delta_listeners}</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        `);
                                                        }
                                                    };
    i++;
    }
```

Can anyone help with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: first of all you need to define var i and var collectionAmount we can get data and go ahead. if that to long code then use jsfiddle and provide link here.

Comment: why not swap the while-loop for a for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

Excellent time to use double filtering! This is why I love Javascript.

const result = first.filter(firstId => second.filter(secondId => firstId.id === secondId.id))

What filter does is that it goes through all the elements in an array and applies logic on it. Since filter takes a function as an argument, it's a perfect way to apply the second filtering on top of it.

If you use bitValues as the first array you'll end up with a list containing the objects in bitValues that are matched in collectionValues.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let table = document.createElement("table");//creating a table element
 $(table).append("<tr></tr>");// inserting a row element in the table
 let head = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];// selecting the row elment previously selected
 for(key in bitValues[0]){//looping through all keys in the object
     $(head).append(`<th>${key}</th>`);// putting each key as a head in the first row of the table
 }
 $(table).append("<tbody></tbody>")// creating a table body
 for(row of bitValues){// looping through each object in bitValues array
      let tr = document.createElement("tr");// creating a row for each object in the array
      for(x in row){// looping through each key of an object in the array
         $(tr).append(`<td>${row[x]}<td>`);// putting the value of each key in a td tag and appending it to tr
      }
      table.appendChild(tr);// appending the tr to the table
 }
 $('.freestyle-deltas_details_bits').append(table);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Ditrix. Thanks for the fast answer. Maybe I've misunderstood you, but code you've sent only partially works (or maybe I'm just making a stupid mistake). It works with the bits refering to collection with the id 2, but all the bits still gets shown displaying the collection 1. The entire code after your answer looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7hawpnjz/). 
Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: nope trying the code  will diplay all the collection elements

Comment: So, I tried to refactor the code, so it doesn't look the same way. It looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r4pstfqg/1/). What happens when I output this is that a "headline" gets created for each type of bit and the different bits gets selected. Out of what I can see is that it should only be "Bit 1" that should be displayed in the first table generated from the first collection and "Bit 2" and "Bit 3" that should be displayed under the second collection, but all the bits gets displayed in the first collection. How come?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what `collectionAmount` is, I'd guess it is just the number of items in `collectionValues`.

What you want is a way, to only render those items from `bitValues`, which have a `collection_id` that corresponds to the `id` of the collection currently being worked on, right? In this case, use a `filter` and a `reduce`. Since you can loose the `filter` by adding a simple `if-else` inside the `reduce`, just use a `reduce`.

First off, let's clean up a bit and move the template into it's own function:

```
  /* template */
  const bitValueTemplate = data => `<tr>
    <td>
      <span class="font-weight-bold">Bit ${data.id}:</span>
      (${data.time}, ${data.seconds} sec)
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="colorChangeByValueDelta">${data.delta}%</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="colorChangeByValueGainLoss">${data.gain_loss}%</span>
    </td>
    <td>${data.total_listeners}</td>
    <td>${data.delta_listeners}</td>
  </tr>`;
```

Now to the tricky bit, which will build a complete HTML string from the list of `bitValues` at once (meaning it contains multiple `<tr>` elements):

```
  /* renders a list into a simple string, only adds items where a certain
  property has a certain value. uses a template function/render function to
  render each item, then adds it to the end of the overall string. returns
  the complete string when finished */
  const renderByPropWith = (prop, value, renderFn, xs) => {
    return xs.reduce((html, x) => {
      if (x[prop] === value) {
        return html + renderFn(x);
      }
      return html;
    }, '');
  }
```

OK, time to try it:

```
  var collectionAmount = collectionValues.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < collectionAmount) {
    // (Code that works)...


    var html = renderByPropWith('collection_id', collectionValues[i].id, bitValueTemplate, bitValues);
    $('.freestyle-deltas_details_bits').append(html);

    i++;
  }
```